# using jquery clone to create div elements, how can I then set the ID tag?

Tags: jquery, string, loops

I have the following block of jQuery code that I'm using to copy some html from one place to another:

```
var newLine  = $('#popup-clone .popup-contents').last().clone();
newLine.find('.popup-title').html("hello world");

$('#popup-container').append(newLine);
```

this runs in a loop several times so the html gets rendered like this:

```
    <div id="popup-container" style="display: block;">
        <div class="popup-contents">
            <a class="close">close this popup</a>
            <span class="popup-title">Title 1</span>
            <span class="popup-description"></span>
            <span class="popup-type"></span>
            <span class="popup-open"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="popup-contents">
            <a class="close">close this popup</a>
            <span class="popup-title">Title 2</span>
            <span class="popup-description"></span>
            <span class="popup-type"></span>
            <span class="popup-open"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and so on

I want to add a unique ID to every div with class="popup-contents" but i'm not sure how i can do that?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use 'attr':  http://api.jquery.com/attr/

```
newLine.attr('id', 'prefix' + someindex)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the id can be unique random then what I've done in the past is used the UUID/GUID generator from [Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript) to generate random ids.

Then it's just a matter of doing

```
newLine.attr( "id", guid );
```

Comment: thanks, however in my specific instance the ID I want to assign specific IDs based on a dataset

Answer (score 1):

You can generally avoid needing to giving cloned elements an id.

The reasons an element typically needs an id is (a) as a reference for CSS styling or (b) so it can be addressed by javascript/jQuery.

In both cases you can address the cloned element at the point it is created.

Answer (score 0):

Use `prop` instead of `attr`:

[jQuery .prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
newLine.prop('id', 'prefix' + someindex)
```